# data from firebase database is not visible into recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage, urlretrieve

I want to retrieve images frm storage to recyclerview but it is not working

```
mFirestore.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("special", s).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                final SpecializedDoctorNameFragment S = new SpecializedDoctorNameFragment();
                final List<DoctorNameStructure> eventList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (final DocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()) {
                    String id = doc.getString("id");

                    final DoctorNameStructure e = new DoctorNameStructure();
                    e.setName(doc.getString("name"));
                    e.setAddress(doc.getString("address"));
                    e.setConsultancy(doc.getString("consultancyFees"));
                    e.setSpecialization(doc.getString("special"));

                    storageReference.child("images/" + id).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            uploadImages();
                            e.setImage(uri.toString());
                            eventList.add(e);
                        }
                    });

                }
                NameAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new NameAdapter(getContext(), eventList, mFirestore);
                recyclerName.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

            } 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: data is not visible on mobile

Answer (score 0):

Listener is executing after your setAdapter. Change the logic of filling the list.

Comment: would be better if you can complete your answer with code sample :-)

Comment: That is not the problem if i am writing the arraylist code outside storageReference it is working fine